# Excel formula to read 2 of 3 cells repeating or not

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I am having trouble getting a formula that will work the way I want:

IF 2 or 3 of the last 3 cells (`A2:A4`) were `b`, AND cell `A5` is `b`, then `C5=+`, otherwise `-`.

IF 2 or 3 of the last 3 cells (`A2:A4`) were `r`, AND cell `A5` is `r`, then `C5=+`, otherwise `-`.

So if column B has:

```
r,b,b,b,r,b,r,b,r,r
```

column C read from the 4th `b` as:

```
+,-,+,-,-,-,+
```

I tried using the `COUNTIF` formula but could not make it work.

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense.  You describe a rule relating to A2:A4, then you give an example in column B.  You have C in quotes, which isn't any kind of standard notation.  You refer to C5, but associate it with the 4th b, which would be in at least row 6.  You say you tried countif, which didn't work, but you don't provide what you did so people can figure out what went wrong.  It would be helpful to include an actual example (like a screenshot), and explain against that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this formula from B4:

`=IF (COUNTIF (A1:A3,A4)>1,"+","-")`